# DROPDOWNBUTTON WITH CLASS - Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

Tags: flutter

Good afternoon, I have a problem that I have already tried to solve on my own for days, but I can not, I hope you can help me.
I have 2 DropdownButton, of which the first one if it changes and the next one loads. When I try to change the second DropdownButton, let's say I choose ACCESSORIES I get the message, lines below I attach the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/models/coleccion.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/providers/coleccion_provider.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/providers/compania_provider.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/services/coleccion_services.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/shared_preference/usuario_shared_preference.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/models/compania.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/models/usuario.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/providers/usuario_provider.dart';
import 'package:app_calimod_pedidos/services/compania_services.dart';

dynamic tempColeccionSelect;

class ProductosPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductosPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductosPageState createState() => _ProductosPageState();
}

class _ProductosPageState extends State<ProductosPage> {
  List<Compania> _companialist;

  Compania _compania;
  Coleccion _coleccion;
  CompaniaServices _companiaServices = new CompaniaServices();
  ColeccionServices _coleccionServices = new ColeccionServices();
  UsuarioPreferences _usuarioPreferences = new UsuarioPreferences();
  String token;

  List<Compania> listcompania;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Compania selectCompania;
    Usuario usuario = Provider.of<UsuarioProvider>(context).getUsuario;
    token = usuario.token;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Pedidos'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  'PEDIDO',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ListarCombos(
                        token: token,
                      )
                    ],
                  ))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListarCombos extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;
  ListarCombos({@required this.token});

  @override
  _ListarCombosState createState() => _ListarCombosState();
}

class _ListarCombosState extends State<ListarCombos> {
  CompaniaServices companiaServices = new CompaniaServices();
  ColeccionServices coleccionServices = new ColeccionServices();
  List<Compania> listcompania;
  List<Coleccion> listcoleccion;
  Compania selectCompania;
  Coleccion _selectColeccion;
  String selectCombo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final coleccionProvider =
        Provider.of<ColeccionProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return Container(
      //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
              // future: companiaServices.obtenerCompania(widget.token),
              future: companiaServices.obtenerCompania(widget.token),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snaphost) {
                if (snaphost.hasData) {
                  listcompania = snaphost.data;
                  return Container(
                      child: DropdownButton<Compania>(
                          hint: Text("Seleccionar"),
                          value: selectCompania,
                          onChanged: (Compania value) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectCompania = value;
                              Provider.of<CompaniaProvider>(context,
                                      listen: false)
                                  .setCompania(value);
                            });
                          },
                          items: listcompania.map((Compania compania) {
                            return new DropdownMenuItem<Compania>(
                              value: compania,
                              child: new Text(
                                compania.name,
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList()));
                } else {
                  return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              }),
          //selectCompania != null ??
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          selectCompania != null
              ? FutureBuilder(
                  future: coleccionServices.obtenerColeccion(
                      widget.token, selectCompania.id),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snaphost) {
                    if (snaphost.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Container(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }

                    if (snaphost.hasData) {
                      listcoleccion = null;
                      listcoleccion = snaphost.data;
                      return DropdownButton<Coleccion>(
                          value: _selectColeccion,
                          hint: Text('Seleccione'),
                          onChanged: (Coleccion value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectColeccion = value;
                            });
                          },
                          items: listcoleccion?.map((Coleccion coleccion) {
                                return new DropdownMenuItem<Coleccion>(
                                  value: coleccion,
                                  child: new Text(
                                    coleccion.name,
                                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                );
                              })?.toList() ??
                              []);
                    } else {
                      return Container(
                        child: Text('Seleccione una Compania'),
                      );
                    }
                  })
              : Container(
                  child: Text('ABC'),
                )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/hacrispin/162345a2a3ee4953c96c41dbe69f47bd
[Imagen ERROR APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFTWn.png)

[Imagen Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNTQ4.png)